# iphone - converting float to integer

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

This is a simple question:

Is this a correct way to get an integer part from a float division?

```
int result = myFloat / anInteger;
```

this is working, but I am not sure if it is the best way.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To truncate:

```
int result = (int)(myFloat / anInteger);
```

Other conversion options:

```
#include <math.h>
int result = (int)ceilf(myFloat / anInteger);
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat / anInteger);
int result = (int)floorf(myFloat / anInteger);
```